# Flex BlazeDS timeout on server side after 60 seconds

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I have an application based on flex client and blazeds at the server side.
Scenario:
1. Client makes a remoting call over secure-amf channel.
2. Server takes some time processing the request usually more than 60 seconds

When server side code tries to write back to the pipe over which the connection is made. it reports broken pipe error.

I have found several queries on this topic without any conclusive solution.

Error log at servier side:
[BlazeDS]java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
Write failed: Broken pipe

Here is my serives-config.xml snippet.

```
<channel-definition id="my-secure-amf"             class="mx.messaging.channels.SecureAMFChannel">
<endpoint url="https://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amfsecure"   class="flex.messaging.endpoints.SecureAMFEndpoint"/>
            <properties>
                <add-no-cache-headers>false</add-no-cache-headers>
            </properties>
</channel-definition>
```

Answer (score 0):

The time-out of your AMF/http connection is set by your Http server application. And depending on what server you are running, you should look for the configuration matching timeout-value. If you are running Apache Tomcat 7, refer to the following configuration:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

There is also a possibility to change the timeout in the services-config.xml: (but this isn't applicable to you)

```
<channel-definition id="my-channel" .... >
  <endpoint url...../>

  <properties>

    <add-no-cache-headers>false</add-no-cache-headers>

    <connect-timeout-seconds>10</connect-timeout-seconds>

  </properties>

</channel-definition>
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction, saved me sometime. I managed to get it working as expected without broken pipe issue. But there seems to be some different issue now. I made the changes on latest version of tomcat 8 using the connectTimeout param that didn't seemed to work. But when i moved/deployed my application on a previous version of tomcat tomcat-7.0.27 it seemed to have worked fine.

Comment: Finally i have found the real root cause of the issue. The timeout was due to the socket_timeout value with default value of 60 seconds. Increasing this value appropriately fixed the issue on tomcat 8 as well as tomcat 7. https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk/workershowto.html

Comment: Where exactly did you set the socket_timeout parameter? Which file?